# Regarding to get the Customer Wishlist using SOAP Web Services

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, soap, wishlist

Can I get the Customer Wishlist of Magento Store using SOAP web services?

Answer (score 3):

Sadly looking into the [main Magento docs](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) this is not possible out of the box. Though it is possible to create your own api in which you could work with the wishlist. For detailed instructions I would suggest reading through: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Steps involve.

1. Creating an XML file that will define the api resource,
2. Adding the resource,
3. Adding errors,
4. Adding ACL,
5. Creating your PHP code,

And it is in step 5 that you could build your code to read the wishlist information of a given customer.